# Some questions about Church's Theorem

Tags: logic, computability

On page.238 of Enderton's "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic", Church's Theorem is stated (The set of Gödel numbers of valid sentences (in the language of R) is not recursive.)

My question is basic. Does it thereby follow that the set of valid sentences of R is not recursive. Why?

I suppose my initial question can be revised: If we show the set of Gödel numbers of valid sentences (in the language of R) is not recursive what relation does this bear to the question about the valid sentences in the language R (why should we care about the Godel numbers, surely it is the valid sentences that we care about). Why does the function mapping elements of the language R to Gödel numbers show us something about the valid sentences in R?

Also, if only sets of numbers can be recursive, and not sets of sentences of R, then why does Enderton write the following sentence after stating Church's theorem, "The set of Gödel numbers of valid wffs is not recursive either, lest the set of valid sentences be recursive." Here he clearly speaks of the set of valid sentences (of R) as being recursive.

Comment: I mean the set of valid sentences in the language of R

Comment: The godel numbering function is computable and 1-1 (given your conventions, it is probably not onto). This means you can computably move from the collection of formulas to their godel numbers. You can also reverse this process computably, hence, a decision procedure for one gives a decision procedure for the other.

Answer (score 3):

This question might be, and therefore my answer will have to be, slightly pedantic. The issue is that in this context the adjective 'recursive' is a property of sets of integers. So, when speaking with complete formality, it's not clear what is meant by saying a set of sentences is recursive or not recursive.

Of course, there is a really nice one-to-one correspondences between sentences and integers: the Gödel numbering. So when we 'step back' to look at the big picture, when we say 'the set of Gödel numbers of valid sentences is not recursive' what we are really saying is 'there is no computational procedure which can perfectly decide whether a given sentence is valid or not'.

So if we dispense with the formality, sure, you can think of it that way.

Comment: Thank you. I am therefore confused why Enderton writes shortly after: "The set of Gödel numbers of valid wffs is not recursive either, lest the set of valid sentences be recursive." Here Enderton is saying something which should be incoherent if you are correct.

Comment: @user65526: "Recursive" is widely used to mean "computable" without particularly caring about which model of computation one is speaking about (thanks to the Church-Turing thesis that they are all equivalent anyway). In the Gödelian definition of "recursive" as being built up from base function using primitive recursion etc., "recursive" strictly speaking applies only to sets of _natural numbers_. However, if we go to Turing machines, for example, it is easy to speak of Turing machines whose native alphabet includes the basic symbols that sentences are made from, and in that case we can ...

Comment: ... certainly speak about whether a set of _actual_ sentences is decidable-by-Turing-machine. Then it is a quite minor transgression against terminology (and a fairly common one) to call such a set "recursive" (or not) instead of "decidable" (or not).

Comment: So in other cases (e.g Trakhtenbrot's theorem) in which a set, or in that case, class, of sentences is said not to be recursive, what sense of "recursive" is at issue. So, I suppose my initial question can be revised: If we show the set of Gödel numbers of valid sentences (in the language of R) is not recursive what relation does this bear to the question about the valid sentences in the language R (why should we care about the Godel numbers, surely it is the valid sentences that we care about).

Comment: @user65526: Let me try to say it in a different way: A set $A$ of symbol strings is decidable _if and only if_ the set $G(A)$ of Gödel numbers for strings in $A$ is decidable, which it is _if and only if_ $G(A)$ is recursive. These equivalences are so  basic in the field that people sometimes use the word "recursive" as a synonym for "decidable" even when talking about $A$ instead of $G(A)$.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this. I think my question is even more basic. It is why we take a result about the Gödel numbers of some class of sentences in R as automatically showing something about those sentences in R. In any case, is Enderton being sloppy in speaking of the set of valid sentences not being recursive?

Comment: It is more that it would be extremely verbose and repetitive to prefix 'Gödel numbers of ' on everything when necessary. It seems Enderton may relax the precision in narrative sections, as long as the theorems remain formal.